# Selection from the table

Tags: python, sqlite

Why when the "WHERE" condition is numeric everything works fine:

```
control_date = "11.2018"
sql =   """
        SELECT date_payment, summa_payment
        FROM payment
        WHERE control_date = {control}
        """
cur.execute(sql.format(control = control_date))
```

And when the symbolic condition returns an error, "OperationalError: no such column: november_2018"

```
control_date = "november_2018"
sql =   """
        SELECT date_payment, summa_payment
        FROM payment
        WHERE control_date = {control}
        """
cur.execute(sql.format(control = control_date))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top control_date is being treated as a number by the query because it only contains numerical characters. As you haven't put the bottom control_date in its own quotes within the ones that begin the string (`"'november_2018'"`) it isn't being treated as a string, so the query tries to parse it as a column name instead.